# Why is queryWeight included for some result scores, but not others, in the same query?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm executing a query_string query with one term on multiple fields, `_all` and `tags.name`, and trying to understand the scoring. Query: `{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"animal","fields":["_all","tags.name"]}}}`. Here are the documents returned by the query:

- **Document 1** has an exact match on `tags.name`, but not on `_all`.
- **Document 8** has an exact match on both `tags.name` and on `_all`.

Document 8 should win, and it does, but I'm confused by how the scoring works out. It seems like Document 1 is getting penalized by having its `tags.name` score multiplied by the IDF twice, whereas Document 8's `tags.name` score is only multiplied by the IDF once. In short:

- They both have a component `weight(tags.name:animal in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity]`.
- In Document 1, we have `weight = score = queryWeight x fieldWeight`.
- In Document 8, we have `weight = fieldWeight`!

Since `queryWeight` contains `idf`, this results in Document 1 getting penalized by its idf twice.

Can anyone make sense of this?

**Additional information**

- If I remove `_all` from the fields of the query, `queryWeight` is completely gone from the explain.
- Adding `"use_dis_max":true` as an option has no effect.

  - However, additionally adding `"tie_breaker":0.7` (or any value) *does* affect Document 8 by giving it the more-complicated formula we see in Document 1.
  - Thoughts: It's plausible that a boolean query (which this is) might do this on purpose to give more weight to queries that match more than one sub-query. However, this doesn't make any sense for a dis_max query, which is supposed to just return the maximum of the sub-queries.

Here are the relevant explain requests. Look for embedded comments.

**Document 1** (match only on `tags.name`):

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/questions/question/1/_explain?pretty' -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"animal","fields":["_all","tags.name"]}}}'`:

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "_index" : "questions_1390104463",
  "_type" : "question",
  "_id" : "1",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.058849156,
    "description" : "max of:",
    "details" : [ {
      "value" : 0.058849156,
      "description" : "weight(tags.name:animal in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
      // weight = score = queryWeight x fieldWeight
      "details" : [ {
        // score and queryWeight are NOT a part of the other explain!
        "value" : 0.058849156,
        "description" : "score(doc=0,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.30685282,
          "description" : "queryWeight, product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            // This idf is NOT a part of the other explain!
            "value" : 0.30685282,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
          }, {
            "value" : 1.0,
            "description" : "queryNorm"
          } ]
        }, {
          "value" : 0.19178301,
          "description" : "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 1.0,
            "description" : "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 1.0,
              "description" : "termFreq=1.0"
            } ]
          }, {
            "value" : 0.30685282,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
          }, {
            "value" : 0.625,
            "description" : "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
          } ]
        } ]
      } ]
    } ]
  }
```

**Document 8** (match on both `_all` and `tags.name`):

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/questions/question/8/_explain?pretty' -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"animal","fields":["_all","tags.name"]}}}'`:

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "_index" : "questions_1390104463",
  "_type" : "question",
  "_id" : "8",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.15342641,
    "description" : "max of:",
    "details" : [ {
      "value" : 0.033902764,
      "description" : "btq, product of:",
      "details" : [ {
        "value" : 0.033902764,
        "description" : "weight(_all:anim in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.033902764,
          "description" : "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 0.70710677,
            "description" : "tf(freq=0.5), with freq of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 0.5,
              "description" : "phraseFreq=0.5"
            } ]
          }, {
            "value" : 0.30685282,
            "description" : "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
          }, {
            "value" : 0.15625,
            "description" : "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
          } ]
        } ]
      }, {
        "value" : 1.0,
        "description" : "allPayload(...)"
      } ]
    }, {
      "value" : 0.15342641,
      "description" : "weight(tags.name:animal in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
      // weight = fieldWeight
      // No score or queryWeight in sight!
      "details" : [ {
        "value" : 0.15342641,
        "description" : "fieldWeight in 0, product of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 1.0,
          "description" : "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 1.0,
            "description" : "termFreq=1.0"
          } ]
        }, {
          "value" : 0.30685282,
          "description" : "idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"
        }, {
          "value" : 0.5,
          "description" : "fieldNorm(doc=0)"
        } ]
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer yourself? Or do you have any source to study? I'm suffering exactly from the same lack of understanding. In our case this penalize some hits a lot and I need to understand why and how to tune our query.

Comment: No, I never found an answer unfortunately.. curious to see what you hear back.

Answer (score 0):

I've no answer. Just want to mention I posted question to the Elasticsearch forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/xBKlFkq0SP0
I'll notify here when I'll get the answer.